# Как в последнем Firefox через Selenium включить поддержку STL 1.0 1.1?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

Как в последнем Firefox через Selenium включить поддержку STL 1.0 и 1.1 ?

Нужный Button через Xpath не находится.

Может через какой-нибудь параметр в about:config ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Исправьте STL На TLS. ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("--tls1"); Вот тут есть все команды  https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @Sergey_73 для Firefox разве подойдет это?

Comment: Попробуй так. FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.AddArgument("--ssl-version-min=tls1");
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer", false);
            IWebDriver web = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
            web.Navigate().GoToUrl("about:config");

Comment: [судя по тестам](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=likest.ru) сайт поддерживает TLS 1.2, но Firefox скорее всего ругается и на поддержку устаревших протоколов, и на поддержку небезопасных протоколов шифрования. Я бы не рекомендовал пользоваться этим сайтом, а если пользоваться, то принудительно включать протокол TLS 1.2